# Need help with a basic table

Tags: tables

I am a beginner. I have been attempting to make a table for the last two days but I am not getting it. I need help with this table. [image: table]

Some of my attempts

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$t$ & $y$ & $y$ \text{in terms of} $y_0[=(-\frac 12) 

g\tau^2]$ &\text{Distance traversed in successive intervals}& \text{Ratio of distances traversed} \
\hline
 $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $:$ & $:$  \
$ \tau$  & $-(\frac 12) g \tau^2$ & $y_0$ & $y_0$ & $1$\
 $2 \tau$ & $-4(\frac 12) g \tau^2$ & $4y_0$ & $3y_0$ & $3$ \
 $3 \tau$ & $-9(\frac 12) g \tau^2$ & $9y_0$ & $5y_0$ & $5$  \
 $4\tau$ & $-16(\frac 12) g \tau^2$ & $16y_0$ &$7y_0$ & $7$  \
 $5 \tau$ & $-25(\frac 12) g \tau^2$ & $25y_0$ & $9y_0$ & $9$ \
 $6 \tau$ & $-36(\frac 12) g \tau^2$& $36y_0$ & $11y_0$ & $11$
\end{tabular}
```

.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$t$ & $y$ & $y$ \text{in terms of} $y_0[=\left(-\frac 12\right) g\tau^2]$ &\text{Distance traversed in successive intervals}& \text{Ratio of distances traversed} \
\hline
 $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $:$ & $:$  \
$ \tau$  & $-\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $y_0$ & $y_0$ & $1$\
 $2 \tau$ & $-4\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $4y_0$ & $3y_0$ & $3$ \
 $3 \tau$ & $-9\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $9y_0$ & $5y_0$ & $5$  \
 $4\tau$ & $-16\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $16y_0$ &$7y_0$ & $7$  \
 $5 \tau$ & $-25\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $25y_0$ & $9y_0$ & $9$ \
 $6 \tau$ & $-36\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$& $36y_0$ & $11y_0$ & $11$ \
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$t$ & $y$ & $y$ \text{in terms of} $y_0[=\left(-\frac 12\right) g\tau^2]$ &\text{Distance traversed in successive intervals}& \text{Ratio of distances traversed} \\
\hline
 $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $\:$ & $\:$  \\
$ \tau$  & $-\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $y_0$ & $y_0$ & $1$\\
 $2 \tau$ & $-4\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $4y_0$ & $3y_0$ & $3$ \\
 $3 \tau$ & $-9\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $9y_0$ & $5y_0$ & $5$  \\
 $4\tau$ & $-16\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $16y_0$ &$7y_0$ & $7$  \\
 $5 \tau$ & $-25\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $25y_0$ & $9y_0$ & $9$ \\
 $6 \tau$ & $-36\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$& $36y_0$ & $11y_0$ & $11$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}   % in case you need it
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{2cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|} % p: col-width
        \hline
        $t$ & 
        $y$ & 
        {$y$ in terms of $y_0=-\frac{1}{2} g \tau^2$} &
        {Distance traversed in successive intervals} & % {} for readability
        {Ratio of distances traversed}\\% \\ ends the row
        
        \hline  % just two lines as an example
        $0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$ &$0$\\    % digits in math-font
        $6 \tau$ & 
        $-3 (\frac{1}{2})g \tau^2$ & % watch braces ;-)
        {$36 y_0$} & {$11 y_0$} &
        {$11$}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment for more details on the `tabular` environment.

Result:

[image]

Unless you know it already, this one is worth spending some hours reading and scanning: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX .

Find more alternatives for table-design here: https://ctan.org/topic/table?lang=en . May be you enjoy `nicematrix` https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix ?

Have a good journey with Latex :)

Answer (score 6):

It is not clear why your code fragment has three consecutive identical tables. Anyway, in suggested solution is consider just one:

[image]

In code for above table is consider `tblr` table environment defined in the package `tabularray` which is nested in math environment. By this are eliminated all `$` in table body:

**Edit:**
In MWE is now considered `tabularray` version 2021N.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { l l  X[l] X[1.1,l] X[l] },
             vlines,
             hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt},  % <---
             colsep=4pt,
             }
t   & y &   y $ in terms of $ y_0\ [=(-\frac{1}{2})g\tau^2] 
            &   $in terms of successive intervals$~
                &   $Ratio of distances traversed$~   \\
0   & 0 & 0 &   &                           \\
\tau  & -(\frac{1}{2}) g \tau^2 
        & y_0   & y_0 & 1                   \\
2\tau & -4(\frac{1}{2}) g \tau^2
        & 4y_0 & 3y_0 & 3     \\
3\tau & -9(\frac{1}{2}) g \tau^2
        & 9y_0 & 5y_0 & 5     \\
4\tau & -16(\frac{1}{2}) g \tau^2
        & 16y_0 &7y_0 & 7     \\
5\tau & -25(\frac{1}{2}) g \tau^2
        & 25y_0 & 9y_0 & 9    \\
6\tau & -36(\frac{1}{2}) g \tau^2
        & 36y_0 & 11y_0 & 11  \\
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution. // There are 3 tables, because the OP wanted to show some of his or her attempts, which got edited into one big source-code later.

Comment: @MS-SPO, thank you for compliment. About three tables: it is still not clear to me. But OP have two possibilities: repeat table body three times (in one big table) or repeat the same table three times.

Answer (score 1):

To create multiple lines in the column header, the `\thead` command from the `makecell` package can be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\theadalign{tl} %for top left alignment

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\thead{$t$} & \thead{$y$} 
& \thead{$y$ in terms of\\ $y_0[=\left(-\frac 12\right) g\tau^2]$} 
& \thead{Distance \\traversed in \\successive \\intervals} 
& \thead{Ratio of \\distances \\traversed} \\
\hline
$0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $\:$ & $\:$  \\
$ \tau$  & $-\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $y_0$ & $y_0$ & $1$ \\
$2 \tau$ & $-4\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $4y_0$ & $3y_0$ & $3$ \\
$3 \tau$ & $-9\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $9y_0$ & $5y_0$ & $5$  \\
$4\tau$ & $-16\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $16y_0$ &$7y_0$ & $7$  \\
$5 \tau$ & $-25\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$ & $25y_0$ & $9y_0$ & $9$ \\
$6 \tau$ & $-36\left(\frac 12\right) g \tau^2$& $36y_0$ & $11y_0$ & $11$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]